# displaying value to the right of a checkbox

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to utilize checkboxes in my sheet. I currently have checkboxes in "Points- Props" Column A:A all the way down. I would like to display the text to the right of the checkbox when it's selected(TRUE) in cell A1 on Player Lookup. I also have another sheet called Rebound-Props set up the same way as Points-Props. I'd like to just hit the checkbox next to the name and it auto-populates in A1 on Player Lookup.

I tried

`=IF('Points- Props'!A4:A=TRUE,'Points- Props'!B4,"")` and a few others and no luck, some give errors such as array value not being found.

[image: Player Lookup]

[image: Point- Prop sheet]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqzTC69oH-1DP_epH0rBsF8jjBaHjmu78TxonIvxOrw/edit#gid=1212903092

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqzTC69oH-1DP_epH0rBsF8jjBaHjmu78TxonIvxOrw/edit#gid=1212903092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF('Points- Props'!A3:A=TRUE, 'Points- Props'!B3:B, ))
```

---

### update:

```
=FILTER('ASSIST- Props'!B3:B, 'ASSIST- Props'!A3:A=TRUE)
```